# Java GeoTools - Getting CRS from SRID

Tags: java, geo

I might confuse between two things, but I need to do some calculation on my polygons (distance, area etc.). Using the WKBReader, I'm getting the geo:

```
WKBReader wkbReader = new WKBReader();
byte[] a = results.getBytes(8);
Geometry geo = wkbReader.read(results.getBytes("st_asbinary"));
```

But I'm not getting it in EPSG:4326. I want to use GeoTools to do the transform. How do I get the CRS from the geo object? (look at the 3 question marks)

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = ???
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
```

MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
Geometry targetGeometry = JTS.transform(geo, transform);
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If a CRS value is set on the geo object then the appropriate method call is:

```
geo.getCoordinateReferenceSystem()
```

If it isn't set on the geometry then you'll need to find a suitable object to get it from.
The [GeoTools Geometry CRS Tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/tutorials/geometry/geometrycrs.html) has some examples (schema, world) and the [GeoTools JavaDoc](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/index-all.html#_G_) has a complete list of getCoordinateReferenceSystem() method declarations/implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to transform the geometry to the default CSR, can I just use the following method: JTS.toGeographic(this.geo, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84); ???

Comment: toGeographic(...) converts into WGS84 so you would use a CRS representing your source CRS as the argument.